# Is there a way to configure node.js to use absolute paths for imports?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What I'm basically trying to achieve is to be able to do:

```js
import {thingOne, thingTwo} from 'functions/myFunctions.js'
```

instead of

```js
import {thingOne, thingTwo} from '../../functions/myFunctions.js'
```

Paths are obviously hypothetical. The idea is that the functions directory exists in the root of the project - in the same directory as package.json.

I've been able to achieve this whilst using React by specifying a baseUrl in jsconfig.json, but that does nothing whilst working with a standard nodejs project. I'd prefer not to use any extra packages/dependencies for this.

I've also tried setting the environment variable NODE_PATH to './', as I've seen suggested elsewhere, but that didn't change anything either.
If it's relevant, I'm using Ubuntu via WSL2, and Node.js v17.7.2. Thank you

Comment: https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/say-good-bye-relative-imports-in-nodejs-projects-65513bcdae6c  This might help you

Comment: This is currently only possible using a transpiler/compiler, like TypeScript or Babel.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78176236/11927087

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [subpath patterns](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/packages.html#subpath-patterns) feature with [subpath imports](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/packages.html#subpath-imports).

Consider this example:

`./package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "so-74050411",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "imports": {
    "#root/*.mjs": "./*.mjs"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

`./src/module.mjs`:

```js
export function greet (name) {
  console.log(`Hello ${name ?? 'world'}`);
}
```

`./src/subdir_a/subdir_b/module_b.mjs`:

```js
import {greet} from '#root/src/module.mjs';

greet('Stack Overflow');
```

Then, running from the project root directory in the terminal:

```
$ node --version
v16.18.0

$ node src/subdir_a/subdir_b/module_b.mjs
Hello Stack Overflow
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using typescript you can do something like this:

tsconfig.json

```js
 ...
 "paths": {
      "data/*": ["src/data/*"],
      "helpers/*": ["src/helpers/*"],
    }
  },
```

here's some resources that can help you: https://plusreturn.com/blog/how-to-configure-a-path-alias-in-a-react-typescript-app-for-cleaner-imports/